# Barplot dplyr summarized values

Tags: r, plot, dplyr

I have data from a top 3 ranking. I'm trying to create a plot that would have on the x axis the column name (cost/product), and the y value be the frequency (ideally relative frequency but I'm not sure how to get that in dplyr).

I'm trying to create this in plotly from values summarized in dplyr. I have a dplyr data frame that looks something like this:

```
likelyReasonFreq<-    LikelyRenew_Reason %>%
      filter(year==3)%>%
      filter(status==1)%>%
      summarize(costC = count(cost), 
                productsC = count(products))



   > likelyReasonFreq
          costC.x   costC.freq   productsC.x  productsC.freq
     1       1         10           1             31
     2       2         11           2             40
     3       3         17           3             30
     4      NA        149          NA             86
```

I'm trying to create a barplot that shows the total (summed) frequency for cost,and for products. So frequency for cost would be the frequency for # of times ranked 1, 2, or 3 so 38. Essentially I'm summing rows 1:3 (for products it would be 101 (not including NA values).

I'm  not sure how to go about this, any ideas??

below is the variable likelyReasonFreq

```
> dput(head(likelyReasonFreq))
 structure(list(costC = structure(list(x = c(1, 2, 3, NA), freq = c(10L, 
  11L, 17L, 149L)), .Names = c("x", "freq"), row.names = c(NA, 
  4L), class = "data.frame"), productsC = structure(list(x = c(1, 
  2, 3, NA), freq = c(31L, 40L, 30L, 86L)), .Names = c("x", "freq"
  ), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("costC", 
  "productsC"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

I appreciate any advice!

Comment: Can you explain how you got the numbers in this: "So frequency for cost would be 38, and for products it would be 101"?

Comment: I'm summing the values in rows 1:3 for the frequency columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data structure is little awkward to work with, you can do a `str` or `glimpse` to it to see the problem, however you may fix this as below and then can plot it.

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ costC    :'data.frame':  4 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x   : num  1 2 3 NA
  ..$ freq: int  10 11 17 149
 $ productsC:'data.frame':  4 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x   : num  1 2 3 NA
  ..$ freq: int  31 40 30 86
```

**Code to follow for plotting:**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
df <- df %>% map(unnest) %>% bind_rows(.id="Name") %>% na.omit() #fixing the structure of column taken as a set of two separate columns

df %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=Name, y= freq)) +
    geom_col()
```

I hope this is what is expected, although I am not entirely sure of it.

**Input data given**:

```
df <- structure(list(costC = structure(list(x = c(1, 2, 3, NA), freq = c(10L, 
  11L, 17L, 149L)), .Names = c("x", "freq"), row.names = c(NA, 
  4L), class = "data.frame"), productsC = structure(list(x = c(1, 
  2, 3, NA), freq = c(31L, 40L, 30L, 86L)), .Names = c("x", "freq"
  ), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("costC", 
  "productsC"), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Added after OP request:**

Here, I have not removed the NAs instead I have relplaced with a new value '4'. To take a relative sum across groups, I have used `cumsum` and then divided by the entire sum across both groups to get the relative frequencies.

```
df <- df %>% map(unnest) %>% bind_rows(.id="Name") 

df[is.na(df$x),"x"] <- 4

df %>% 
    group_by(Name) %>% 
    mutate(sum_Freq = sum(freq), cum_Freq = cumsum(freq)) %>% 
    filter(x == 3) %>% 
    mutate(new_x = cum_Freq*100/sum_Freq) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=Name, y = new_x)) +
    geom_col()
```

Comment: This works fantastic! Do you have any idea how I might get the relative frequency? Meaning for cost it would be 38/187 * 100 = 20.3%

Comment: 187 = 10 + 11+ 17 +149

Comment: @ElaineSlaven , Not clear, what about productsC (31+40+30)/86 which is greater than 100% which is not possible. but you can do proportions using plots, by  using `..count../sum(..count..)`

Comment: the relative freq would be the sum of rows 1:3 over the sum of all rows 1:4. So productsC would be 101/187

Comment: sorry can you provide the code for how you got the rfreq values? did you use summarize?

Comment: @ElaineSlaven Added the code as per your request. Request you to add every question in your original post always. Thanks